# Stata 'use if' function in R

Tags: r, stata

Is there a way to load a .dta file based on specific criteria.

For instance, in Stata you can load a file using: `use if vara==1 using "some/file/path"`

I have seen older posts here regarding loading only a specific number of observations, but haven't seen a post addressing this functionality.

Comment: Are you talking about doing this in R? If I understand correctly, you can just use `if (var1==1) read.dta("filepath")` or something similar.

Comment: exactly. or `ifelse` should you need an `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to the first part, you can do a simple `if..else` or you could do something like this:

```
#Type of file
type=c(2)
#Variable to store your file
fn=switch(i,"filename1","filename2","filename3")
# fn now is "filename2"
```

> regarding loading only a specific number of observations

This is possible. The easiest way is to check the manual for your `read.csv()` function. Type the following in the R prompt: `help(read.csv)`. A help window will open showing the documentation. You can observe the signature of your fuction of interest:

`read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
         dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)`

and below, one of the allowed parameters to this function is the one you are looking for:

`nrows integer: the maximum number of rows to read in. Negative and other invalid values are ignored.`

Answer (score 1):

The following randomly assigns a 0 or 1 to a variable called `vara` and reads it in from 1 of 2 different csv files, depending on the value of `vara`:

```
data(iris)

write.csv(iris,"iris.csv")
write.csv(iris1,"iris1.csv")

vara <- ifelse(rnorm(1) > .15,1,0) # randomly assign a 1 or 0

# Stata: use if vara==1 using "some/file/path"

new_data <- ifelse(vara==1,read.csv("iris.csv"),read.csv("iris1.csv"))
```

I assume you're just asking about how to conditionally read a file in R like you did in Stata. If you mean also how to actually read your old `dta` files, then you should additionally use a special function from one of the libraries that do so, like `read.dta` mentioned by @thelatemail in a comment (see also: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.dta.html).

If you're reading in common file types (e.g. csv) and they are very large then consider using `fread` from `data.table` or `read_csv` from `readr`.